# Deleted the /etc/bind folder, any way to get the contents back?

Tags: bind, restore, undelete

So I was following a tutorial to set up a DNS server and I mistyped some things and want to start over, so I end up deleting the /etc/bind folder, thinking that reinstalling bind9 will restore the original files.

Welp, I reinstalled bind9 and turns out these

[image: files]

weren't included in the install package.. is there anyway I can restore the files or download it atleast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get -o DPkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" --reinstall install bind9
```

Comment: thank you so much !  i was worried no one would even bother to answer this. Thanks !

Comment: yeah, it's kind of offtopic here...

Comment: btw do you have suggestion on where to ask questions like this? superuser/ubuntu forum ?

Comment: It's askubuntu.com. Actually [I got answer from here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26228/how-can-i-reinstall-apache-httpd-after-deleting-some-of-the-configuration-files)

Comment: @Anubioz: Running a DNS server on Ubuntu *in a professiona/business* setting is very much on topic here (it's OT if in a home/hobby environment). It's often a bad idea to run your own DNS, but sometimes is it necessary. [ubuntu.se] generally is an Ubuntu-specific subset of [SU] and [unix.se]